# WAMP Server Unavailable while VPN is connected

Tags: vpn, wamp

WAMP is installed on a desktop machine.

That machine is behind a Linksys Router which uses NAT to forward incoming connections on port 80.

Windows Firewall is off.

Symptom...

My configuration works perfectly for all 8 sites I have hosted on this one PC except when I connect to another network via VPN connection.

When the desktop is connected to VPN none of the sites are reachable.

I have already gone into Advanced Options under connections and made sure my LAN connection is listed ABOVE my VPN connection.

I have specified the LAN IP address as the IP address to Listen to in Apache configuration and vhost files and on all Virtual Hosts.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it shortly after I posted this question.

I had to go into the connection properties of the VPN connection and UNCHECK - "Use default gateway on remote network" for both IPV6 and IPV4